# Catching lambda functions capturing local temporaries

Tags: c++, lambda

I've recently discovered a couple of lambdas in our codebase which work most of the time, but are relying on undefined behaviour. Here is an example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

std::thread thread;

void foo(int bar)
{
    thread = std::thread([&]() { std::cout << bar << std::endl; });
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    foo(5);
    thread.join();
}
```

The problem being that a variable with local scope (bar) is captured by reference and accessed at a later time. Strangely, none of our compilers (GCC, Clang, MSVC) warn about this by default even if it should be as easy to catch as "warning: returning address of local temporary object". Is there a way to make any of the mentioned compilers warn about this?

Comment: Who is returning the address of a local variable now?

Comment: “it should be easy to catch” is a bold statement. Replace `std::thread` by `magic_box` in your code and tell me whether the compiler should still warn about this.

Comment: There is no UB in code you posted. All variables lifetime is not ended when you are accessing them.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Right, fixed that.

Comment: Lifetime was not bound to type contrary to Rust. So without knowing `std::thread` internal (to know if it store the lambda or just use it), we cannot know if `foo` is correct or not (We know that thread co a copy, but not from given code).

Answer (score 1):

This caught me out recently too. I realised I was capturing function args by reference bloomin' *everywhere*.

I'd love to get a warning about this in such cases, but I suspect the reason we don't is that in many cases there's nothing wrong with the capture. As long as you execute the lambda immediately, you're safe. It's only when you store it for later use (including within a worker thread) that you may have problems.

Either compilers just aren't clever enough yet, or their authors have decided not to warn on this.

Whatever the case, I'm not aware of any mainstream compilers that'll warn on your code. So you'll just have to be really careful.

Comment: `Either compilers just aren't clever enough yet`. Compiler cannot be clever in this case because they can understand only the language constructs, Not the threading libraries. -1, because you are answering the same thing from my answer with little more decorations & your own 'feelings'.

Comment: @iammilind: I did not "irresponsibly" downvote you, and my answer is not at all the same as yours. On the other hand, you _are_ downvoting "irresponsibly" because, as you just admitted, you are doing it based on the person not on the post. Get a grip.

Comment: @iammilind: _"Compiler cannot be clever in this case because they can understand only the language constructs, Not the threading libraries"_ Utter nonsense. First of all, the threading library _comes with the compiler_; it can absolutely understand it. Second, compilers don't _need_ to know anything about how the lambda will be used to know that there _could_ be UB here.

Comment: I downvoted becoz you appeared to set the standard very high for perfection in my answer & in such case "the cleverness of compilers" as mentioned in your answer is incorrect. As your comment about "threading library comes with compiler" thing, is very naive. That means only `std::thread` can be detected. Read my answer again. What about other threading libraries? Compiler won't be able to understand those. By writing following statement: "Either compilers just aren't clever enough yet, or their authors have decided not to warn on this.", you expect those compilers & writers to be magicians!!

Comment: @iammilind: _"I downvoted because you appear to set the standard very high for perfection"_ What a silly reason to downvote. Yet you accuse _me_ of being irresponsible. Blimey.

Comment: _"That means only std::thread can be detected. Read my answer again. What about other threading libraries? Compiler won't be able to understand those."_ I addressed that in the very next sentence, @iammilind. Read **my** answer again, iammilind. Do you see where it says _"in many cases there's nothing wrong with the capture."_, iammilind?

Comment: @iammilind do not vandalize answers because you disagree with the person who wrote it, ever.  You clearly knew the original writer would disagree with your edit.  It was not clarifying the original author's intent, or fixing an oops the original author would agree with, or even a good faith attempt at any of this.  Bad cricket.

Comment: @Yakk, Questioning compiler's smartness is not something I am still convinced to. I know that the author was in disagreement. But the "taunting" was going on and on from him/her, probably due to my downvote. 5 minutes had already passed. I didn't want to stretch further at the same time I didn't want the author to be in agony of -2. Hence, I edited the part which I felt IS wrong. At the same time, instead of deleting it, I made it visibly "striked". This is how I can remove my vote & author can re-edit it. I couldn't have done better than this(adding space?). Upto you, if you see it wrong way.

Comment: @iammilnd I do not care if you are right.  I do not care if you downvoted or recinded it.  I see you disagree: that is acceptable.  What you did was disagree, not convince the original answerer, then unilaterally impose your position when you could not convince.  That is not what editing is for on SO.  Disagree, downvote, walk away.  Don't do a spurious vandalism edit you know will be reverted and undo the downvote just to get back the 1 rep you spent on the downvote.  Have you done this before?

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning address of a temporary variable. Passing reference of a temporary variable is fine. Ofcourse, when you pass a variable by reference to a thread then it may lead to unexpected outcomes if the source function has expired from which the temporary variable was originally passed.

But, compiler doesn't care about the thread creation and threading order. Because people may use their own threading library instead of `std::thread`. From compiler perspective, it just looks for the validity of the language construct and `[&](...){}` is a valid construct.

In other words, there is no way for compiler to catch this (actually useful) warning. Sadly it's a programmer's responsibility. You may copy `argv` to a `std::string` object and pass it by value.

Comment: "Passing reference of a temporary variable is fine" Well yes, but most programmers realize it is bad form to save the address to those references and access them later. Very few programmers would write code like this: int* temp = nullptr;
void foo(int& bar)
{
    temp = &bar;
}

Comment: _"Passing reference of a temporary variable is fine."_ What? No it's not.... You have no way of knowing when the thread will access that variable through the reference.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, the sentence for which you downvoted is not in context of "thread". But in general, passing variable to a function is Ok. Regarding "threads" I have already clarified in the 2nd statement, that compiler doesn't know whether you are passing a variable by reference to a thread or a normal function. The question is about whether compiler should be able to issue a warning or not. The answer is "NO", because warning can be issued for borderline cases & passing variable by reference is a very valid idiom in C++.